# OpenShift message queue

Tags: jboss, message-queue, openshift, hornetq

I'd like to host apps that uses queue to communicate with each other on OpenShift.
One kind of apps - producers will put some data to the queue and another type - consumer will process the message. My question is how to implement message queue. I've thought about two approaches:

1. Create an app with JBoss, HornetQ and consumer and create proxy port for HornetQ, so that producers can send messages there.
2. Create an app with JBoss and consumer, and make a JBoss's HornetQ available to producers. It sounds a bit better for me, but I don't know if I can make queue available to producers and how it works if there are more instances of consumer on different nodes (and different JBoss instances).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how else to answer you besides showing you a link on how to use Wildfly. You can just use the Wildfly Cartridge:

https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/wildfly-8

If you provide me some extra context I can try to enrich the answer a bit better. I need to know what is your problem, and what's not working.

If you just want to know how to configure Wildfly with HornetQ, the Wildfly cartridge I posted is the way to go.

Comment: Can you provide any information on how this solution scales? The data in the queue will be the same for each wildfly instance that hosts my application? How can I make this queue available from outside of wildfly (applications from another cartridge)? In this case proxy ports doesn't look like correct solution. I'm thinking about architecture of my university project and my problem is where to place queue to make it available for consumers (they will be probably part of a cartridge with hornetQ) and producers (some other applications).

Comment: the discussion here would be diverging the original question... why don't you accept this answer and open another question. or if you want a real discussion about this the place to go will be HornetQ User's forum.